# converting date/time format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question is similar to some other questions here in Stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me. I have date and time column in the format `1991-04-01 00:00:00.000`, and I want to convert it to this format: `19910401`

I have tried this code below:

```
 Update [TestFamily].dbo.List  
 set dbo.List.DtBirth = convert(
 varchar(10), cast(dbo.List.DtBirth as
 datetime ),112)
```

after executing it says 320104 rows affected , but actually nothing has changed , the date format remains the same.

Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the `data type` of `DtBirth` column?

Comment: Which dbms? (Too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: Brackets suggest sql server

Comment: `datetime` columns don't *have* a format. They store the datetime value in a binary form (which actually stores the number of whole days since 01/01/1900 and the fraction of a day). Any formatting concerns need to be dealt with when you convert from datetime to a *string*. Ideally, you do this as close as possible to the point where you output this data to the user - e.g. in your presentation code. Just leave it as a `datetime` in the database.

Comment: try creating a view ... the datatype datetime is not a string.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` data in SQL Server doesn't *have* a format.  They are just values that are only changed to a certain format when you *display* them.  So it is taken into account when you view the results of a query in SSMS, show them in an app, report, etc.

Displaying dates is *almost always* the job of the *display layer*, not the database.  I would strongly suggest making this change at that level (report, app, etc.)  rather than at the SQL level.  Otherwise, you'll have issues with sorting, filtering, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are trying to use an update. SQL updates change values, not data types. You are trying to create a different datatype, a char or varchar.
The field dbo.List.DtBirth is presumably a datetime, and your update does not change that. You could add another field, perhaps called DTBirthAsVarChar varchar(8), then update that based on the date field.

```
Update [TestFamily].dbo.List  
set dbo.List.DTBirthAsVarChar = convert(
varchar(10), cast(dbo.List.DtBirth as
datetime ),112)
```

You also don't need both a convert and a cast in the same statement, they basically do the same thing.

Comment: Be _very_ careful using a different field to represent one field in a different way.  You need to make sure you have good processes in place to ensure that the values are always in sync.  A calculated field would be a better choice.